# Change paragraph text based on form input

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML form where the input, on `onkeyup` should then be 1/input x 96. The answer to this equation should be used to change a paragraph of text

This is what I have tried:

```
<input type="text" name="chance" value="" onkeyup="document.getElementById('sidetextdyn').value=this.value?1/this.value*98:''" >
```

For some reason this does not work. I wish to use this to change the paragraph.

```
<p id="sidetextdyn">1.92x</p>
```

Also, how would I limit the answer to 2 decimal places. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change value with innerHTML since #sidetextdyn is a paragraph element not an input element:

```
onkeyup="document.getElementById('sidetextdyn').innerHTML=this.value?1/this.value*98:''"
```

Comment: Thanks worked great, what about the second part of the question? How would I limit the answer to two decimal places?

Comment: Use toFixed(2) method: this.value?1/this.value*98..toFixed(2)

Comment: Like this? `this.value?1/this.value*98..toFixed(2):''"` does not seem to work.

Comment: (this.value?1/this.value*98).toFixed(2) ??

Comment: It's night here. Glad to help.